# DAX / PowerBi: How to get the products that are NOT on stock?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have 3 tables: STOCK, COLORPRICE, PRODUCT
The relationship between them is:
PRODUCT.PRODUCT = COLORPRICE.PRODUCT (1 to many)
COLORPRICE.EAN = STOCK.EAN (1 to many)

Now I would like to get in a PowerBi Visualisation the active products which are not in our stock.
That means which are not available in "STOCKROOM" and/or "EXPEDITION"
AND
where PUBLIC = "Y" and ACTIVE = "Y"
From my sample that should deliver PRODUCT 'aaa 111333555777' and 'bbb 222333555666'.

My sample perhaps looks a bit complex, but this is it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This measure should return "Not In Stock" when the product is missing or BLANK() when it's not active or public or in expedition or stockroom. It can be used in a matrix visual with Product[Product] on the rows, then only the missing product would be listed.

```
Not In Stock =
IF(
    ISINSCOPE( 'PRODUCT'[PRODUCT] ),
    IF(
        CALCULATE(
            ISEMPTY( STOCK ),
            'PRODUCT'[PUBLIC] = "Y",
            COLORPRICE[ACTIVE] = "Y",
            STOCK[LOCATION] IN { "stockroom", "expedition" }
        ),
        "Not In Stock"
    )
)
```

Edit:

to make it work at the EAN level, we can iterate over the COLORPRICE table and perform the check at the COLORPRICE row level. To aggregeate the result at the product level we may set a product Non In Stock when at least one of its EAN is out of stock. This is not tested, but I hope it will work :)

```
Not In Stock =
IF(
    ISINSCOPE( 'PRODUCT'[PRODUCT] ),
    IF(
        SELECTEDVALUE( 'PRODUCT'[PUBLIC] ) = "Y",
        IF(
            SUMX(
                FILTER( COLORPRICE, COLORPRICE[ACTIVE] = "Y" ),
                IF(
                    CALCULATE(
                        ISEMPTY( STOCK ),
                        STOCK[LOCATION] IN { "stockroom", "expedition" }
                    ),
                    1
                )
            ) > 0,
            "Not In Stock"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: This kind of works. The thing I miss is that it's the combination of "product" with "size" and "color" or the product combined with "ean" that's making one row unique. Now it's showing me per "product" which is "not on stock". As soon as I place "size" and/or "color" next in my matrix, there are no values available for "not in stock". I'd like to see which "ean" (unique item) is "not on stock".

Comment: I added a measure that should work at the EAN level. It "should" since I did not test it. In case it still doesn't work, could you share some sample pbix or the data tables in machine readable format? it's enough to copy-paste from excel or powerbi here https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/ to get a table in markdown format to copy into stack overlow.